# mysql match against with concat_ws not working

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql. I am trying following query which is not working

```
select CONCAT_WS(field1,field2) AS a,field3 from mytable where match(concat_ws(field1,field2),field3) against(' +540211' IN boolean mode)  order by field1,field2;
```

field1 and field2 are varchar(4) each.
I wish to use concat or concat_ws for field1 and field2 because it has numeric values. I also with to use match against for all three fields viz. field1,field2 and field3 if input text is non numeric. field2 is long text field.

Comment: `concat_ws` interprets first parameter as a separator. `concat_ws(field1, field2)` would produce just the value of `field2`. You probably need to add first argument (for example, ',' to concat using commas), or change `concat_ws` to `concat`.

Comment: Although I would not use fulltext search on 12 characters...